# Solace Appliance 3530/3560

Tags: solace, solace-mq

As I know solace use modified Linux , Is there anyway we can find the Linux version of Solace Appliance.

Show version displayed the Solace appliance TR-version but wanted to know the which veriosn/flavor of Linux is used for solace appliance.

Answer (score 4):

This is dependent on the version of SolOS that the appliance is running. SolOS 7.2 uses a modified CentOS 7.2 for its control plane.

Comment: Thanks Alexandra Masse.